# module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'decimal'

Tags: pyarrow

Trying to set the datatype to decimal. I get an error that pyarrow doesn't have the attribute `decimal`

```
>>> import pyarrow
>>> pyarrow.decimal(8)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'decimal'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that `pa.decimal128(18)` works